# What aspects of resource isolation have been done in aws aurora？

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I want to known what kinds of resource isolation in AWS Aurora have been done, such as: cpu/memory/disk iops/bandwidth. And I'm not found relevant information in aurora official website. Can someone tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find that every instance class has its resource limition. URL: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html